# Why does $\int_{-R}^R\int_{-\sqrt{R^2-x^2}}^\sqrt{R^2-x^2}\frac{2R(R^2-x^2)}{\sqrt{R^2-x^2-y^2}}dy\,dx$ have a negative value?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I was trying to compute an integral. $$\int_{-R}^R\int_{-\sqrt{R^2-x^2}}^\sqrt{R^2-x^2}\frac{2R(R^2-x^2)}{\sqrt{R^2-x^2-y^2}}dy\,dx$$ when i calculated the first inner integral i got   $$-4iR(R^2-x^2)(arsinh({{\sqrt\frac{R^2-x^2}{\sqrt{x^2-R^2}}))}}$$ which simplifies to $$4iRln(i)(R^2-x^2)$$ but when i calculated the outer integral i got a negative value. But the real answer is positive.
$$\frac{8R^4\pi}{3}$$
What is wrong with my solution?

Comment: The inner integral is the integral of a non-negative function. How can it be purely imginary?

Comment: I used substitution of a complex function. To make inner integral simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we look at the real value. It is an integral in the x,y - plane over a circle of radius R. In polar coordinates

```
      Integrate[
         Integrate[(2 r R (R^2 - r^2 Cos[\[Phi]]^2))/
                               Sqrt[-r^2 + R^2], 
                {r, 0, R}], 
                   {\[Phi], 0, 2 \[Pi]}]

              (8 \[Pi] R^4)/3 if Re[R]>0  &&  Im[R]==0
```

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \ d\phi \ \int_0^R \  r \ dr  \frac{2\ R \ (R^2 - r^2\ \cos^2 \phi)}{\sqrt{R^2-r^2}} \ = \ \frac{8 }{3} \ \pi \ R^4$$

the extra r coming from $dx dy = r dr d\phi$.

Doing the integrals in the Cartesian map needs

```
        Integrate[(2 R^3 - 2 R x^2)/Sqrt[R^2 - x^2 - y^2], y]
            
                2 (R^3 - R x^2) ArcTan[y/Sqrt[R^2 - x^2 - y^2]]
```

that seems not to have a limit

```
           2 (R^3 - R x^2) ArcTan[y/Sqrt[R^2 - x^2 - y^2]]  /. 
              {y -> Sqrt[R^2 - x^2]}
```

But that not true.

If the denominator goes to zero and the numerator is finite, the limit of the arctan is $\pm \pi/2$ depending on the sign of the numerator.

The mathematical condition  obviously is, that the Limit is done from the inner of the circle.

From the outside, the value is different, left a the other exercise.

Thats the conundrum of the Cauchy  kernel $\frac{1}{r}$ as a distribution, that has $\Delta \frac{1}{r} = 0$ but the surface integral yields $2 \pi$.